# biblatex same first author same year: cite as “a”, “b” etc

Tags: biblatex

In the below file, I wanted the three references to be cited as Inger et al 2006a, Inger et al 2006b and Inger et al 2006c. Can I achieve this using biblatex? If not, can I make alterations to my .bib file that will achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=50]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{IngerEtAl2006a,
  title={Using daily ration models and stable isotope analysis to predict biomass depletion by herbivores},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Mackie, Kerry and Robinson, James A and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Applied Ecology},
  volume={43},
  number={5},
  pages={1022--1030},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  tag={}
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006b,
  title={Prey choice affects the trade-off balance between predation and starvation in an avian herbivore},
  author={Inger, Richard and Bearhop, Stuart and Robinson, James A and Ruxton, Graeme},
  journal={Animal Behaviour},
  volume={71},
  number={7},
 pages={1335--1341},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006c,
  title={Temporal and intrapopulation variation in prey choice of wintering geese determined by stable isotope analysis},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Robinson, James A and Jackson, Andrew L and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Animal Ecology},
  volume={75},
  number={5},
  pages={1190--1200},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

    \cite{IngerEtAl2006a}\\\\
    \cite{IngerEtAl2006b}\\\\
    \cite{IngerEtAl2006c}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `uniquelist=false` helps? - It seems to do what you want though the sorting might not be entirely to your liking. `IngerEtAl2006a` got a "b" and `IngerEtAl2006b` an "a" here, but that can be adjusted via `sortyear` if you insist.

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer a,b,c in the .bib file to match a,b,c in the PDF. What exactly do you mean by "adjusted via `sortyear`"? I tried `sorting=nyt` but this didn't solve problem

Comment: For a similar problem and discussion see [biblatex keys inside editor are not equal to printed bib keys](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250449/35864). The problem is that since the works are strictly speaking by different authors, `biblatex` does not want to sort the entries as belonging to the same author in the bibliography, unless you also specify `sortname = {Inger, Richard}` for all entries. You would then also add `sortyear = {2006-1}` for the *a* entry, `sortyear = {2006-2}` for *b* and finally `sortyear = {2006-3}` for *c* all in your `.bib` file to get the desired sorting.

Comment: See also [BibLaTeX doesn't cite bibliography uniformly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67033/35864), [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864), [Biblatex: Have only one author in citation — multiple articles with same first author, different year](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17838/35864) and [Biblatex authoryear-icomp: maxnames not working or I don't get it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41868/35864)

Comment: Related: [natbib same author same year: cite as "a", "b" etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251103)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want all of the citations to be "Inger et al.", you will need to set `uniquename=false`.

This will not solve the sorting problem since still for `biblatex` all three articles were written by a different set of authors, and the bibliography is sorted first and foremost by authors. Because Mr Bearhop is second author in `IngerEtAl2006b` that paper comes before the two others which have Mr Ruxton as second author when sorting.

You can now do two things.

You could make your bibliography display only a maximum of two names as well, as in

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxnames=2, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
```

Of course then all citations are sorted under "Inger, Richard et al." and then the title is consulted to sort the entries.

Alternatively, you can force `biblatex` to sort all entries under "Inger, Richard et al." by adding

```
sortname = {Inger, Richard and others},
```

to the entries.

In any case, now the citations will all be sorted as if "Inger, Richard et al." was the author.

Now the order still is not right since the alphabetic order of the titles does not coincide with your order, so we can add the `sortyear` field as follows (this is how it would look like if you also add `sortname`, see the MWEs below for more)

```
@article{IngerEtAl2006a,
  title={Using daily ration models and stable isotope analysis to predict biomass depletion by herbivores},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Mackie, Kerry and Robinson, James A and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Applied Ecology},
  volume={43},
  number={5},
  pages={1022--1030},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  sortyear = {2006-1},
  sortname = {Inger, Richard and others},
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006b,
  title={Prey choice affects the trade-off balance between predation and starvation in an avian herbivore},
  author={Inger, Richard and Bearhop, Stuart and Robinson, James A and Ruxton, Graeme},
  journal={Animal Behaviour},
  volume={71},
  number={7},
 pages={1335--1341},
  year={2006},
  sortyear = {2006-2},
  sortname = {Inger, Richard and others},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006c,
  title={Temporal and intrapopulation variation in prey choice of wintering geese determined by stable isotope analysis},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Robinson, James A and Jackson, Andrew L and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Animal Ecology},
  volume={75},
  number={5},
  pages={1190--1200},
  sortyear = {2006-3},
  sortname = {Inger, Richard and others},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

Where the *a* entry gets `sortyear = {2006-1}`, the *b* entry `sortyear = {2006-2}` and *c* `sortyear = {2006-3}`.
For another example of the `sortyear` field have a look at the `knuth:ct` entries in [`biblatex-examples.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib).

MWE for `sortname`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
            maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=999,
            uniquelist=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{IngerEtAl2006a,
  title={Using daily ration models and stable isotope analysis to predict biomass depletion by herbivores},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Mackie, Kerry and Robinson, James A and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Applied Ecology},
  volume={43},
  number={5},
  pages={1022--1030},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  sortyear = {2006-1},
  sortname = {Inger, Richard and others},
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006b,
  title={Prey choice affects the trade-off balance between predation and starvation in an avian herbivore},
  author={Inger, Richard and Bearhop, Stuart and Robinson, James A and Ruxton, Graeme},
  journal={Animal Behaviour},
  volume={71},
  number={7},
 pages={1335--1341},
  year={2006},
  sortyear = {2006-2},
  sortname = {Inger, Richard and others},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006c,
  title={Temporal and intrapopulation variation in prey choice of wintering geese determined by stable isotope analysis},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Robinson, James A and Jackson, Andrew L and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Animal Ecology},
  volume={75},
  number={5},
  pages={1190--1200},
  sortyear = {2006-3},
  sortname = {Inger, Richard and others},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
One \cite{IngerEtAl2006a}, Two \cite{IngerEtAl2006b}, Three \cite{IngerEtAl2006c}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how the sorting by names is severely messed up here.

---

MWE for `maxnames=2`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
            maxnames=2,
            uniquelist=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{IngerEtAl2006a,
  title={Using daily ration models and stable isotope analysis to predict biomass depletion by herbivores},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Mackie, Kerry and Robinson, James A and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Applied Ecology},
  volume={43},
  number={5},
  pages={1022--1030},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  sortyear = {2006-1},
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006b,
  title={Prey choice affects the trade-off balance between predation and starvation in an avian herbivore},
  author={Inger, Richard and Bearhop, Stuart and Robinson, James A and Ruxton, Graeme},
  journal={Animal Behaviour},
  volume={71},
  number={7},
 pages={1335--1341},
  year={2006},
  sortyear = {2006-2},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006c,
  title={Temporal and intrapopulation variation in prey choice of wintering geese determined by stable isotope analysis},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Robinson, James A and Jackson, Andrew L and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Animal Ecology},
  volume={75},
  number={5},
  pages={1190--1200},
  sortyear = {2006-3},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
One \cite{IngerEtAl2006a}, Two \cite{IngerEtAl2006b}, Three \cite{IngerEtAl2006c}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how the sorting makes slightly more sense here, but of course at the expense of dropping all co-authors.

Comment: The best solution is of course to let `biblatex` do all of its stuff and not tinker with the sorting too much. The first step is to stop using bibkeys with `a`, `b`, `c` etc. or at least to not expect `biblatex` to match its disambiguation letters with yours.

Comment: that's such a helpful answer you've given above. But after all that , I think the solution is indeed to stop using `a`, `b`, `c` in keys

Comment: @luciano I'm glad you liked the answer, and it is even nicer for me to know that the answer got you on the right (in my eyes at least) way of not using `a`, `b`, `c` in bibkeys - or at least not expecting the letters to be reflected in the actual document.

Comment: Is there a solution for the same issue in bibtex instead of bibtatex?

Comment: @user200301 That would be a new question. It strongly depends on the style you are using. In general it is probably going to be a bit more difficult.