# References appears with author's full names

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I face a problem with BibTeX, which for just two particular references appear with the author's full names.
I used scholar google to get the BibTeX file. 
the references `\cite{hughes2018comparison}`  and `\cite{hughes2018dynamic}`  publishes in the same year and with the same first author that appears with authors full names. I don't like to show all the authors names in the main text like `(Hughes, El Saeiti and Garca-Fi~nana, 2018) (Hughes, Komarek, Czanner and Garcia-Fi~nana, 2018).` 
I like a `(Hughes et al. 2018a) and (Hughes et al. 2018b)`.

I include another two references that publishes with same author and same year and appear like `(McCulloch and Neuhaus, 2011a) (McCulloch and Neuhaus, 2011b)`

How can I achieve this  `(Hughes et al. 2018a) and (Hughes et al. 2018b)`?

Bibtex file here:

```
@Article{komarek2010discriminant,
  author    = {Kom{\'a}rek, Arno{\v{s}}t and Hansen, Bettina E and Kuiper, Edith MM and van Buuren, Henk R and Lesaffre, Emmanuel},
  title     = {Discriminant analysis using a multivariate linear mixed model with a normal mixture in the random effects distribution},
  journal   = {Statistics in medicine},
  year      = {2010},
  volume    = {29},
  number    = {30},
  pages     = {3267--3283},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
}

@Article{hughes2018dynamic,
  author    = {Hughes, David M and Kom{\'a}rek, Arno{\v{s}}t and Czanner, Gabriela and Garcia-Fi{\~n}ana, Marta},
  title     = {Dynamic longitudinal discriminant analysis using multiple longitudinal markers of different types},
  journal   = {Statistical methods in medical research},
  year      = {2018},
  volume    = {27},
  number    = {7},
  pages     = {2060--2080},
  publisher = {SAGE Publications Sage UK: London, England},
}

@Article{hughes2018comparison,
  author    = {Hughes, David M and El Saeiti, Riham and Garc{\'\i}a-Fi{\~n}ana, Marta},
  title     = {A comparison of group prediction approaches in longitudinal discriminant analysis},
  journal   = {Biometrical Journal},
  year      = {2018},
  volume    = {60},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {307--322},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
}

@Article{mcculloch2011prediction,
  author    = {McCulloch, Charles E and Neuhaus, John M},
  title     = {Prediction of random effects in linear and generalized linear models under model misspecification},
  journal   = {Biometrics},
  year      = {2011},
  volume    = {67},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {270--279},
  publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
}

@Article{mcculloch2011misspecifying,
  author    = {McCulloch, Charles E and Neuhaus, John M},
  title     = {Misspecifying the shape of a random effects distribution: why getting it wrong may not matter},
  journal   = {Statistical science},
  year      = {2011},
  pages     = {388--402},
  publisher = {JSTOR},
}
@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

I show here 
[image]

Comment: The problem here is that the authors of the two papers are different - "Hughes et al." would refer to two diferent sets of people. So biblatex includes more names in order disambiguate. You can disable this functionality with the `uniquelist=false` package option. For more details, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251285/biblatex-same-first-author-same-year-cite-as-a-b-etc

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker - It would appear to be the case that the OP chose the `biblatex` tag in error. Hence, the posting isn't a duplicate of the posting you've referenced.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: There are some examples on, e.g., https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_citation_styles to show how this can be done with `natbib`.

Comment: @Marijn - If the OP uses a bibliography style such as `agsm` or `dcu`, there's nothing `natbib` can do to enable the display of truncated ("Hughes et al") citation call-outs. We really need to find out which bibliography style is being used.

Comment: @Mico you're right of course - but if the OP has difficulty understanding exactly how everything works I thought they might be interested in a simple example that gives the desired result.

Comment: @Mico i use 'agsm' style and natbib  package

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker I tried your option, but not solve it.

Comment: So, to summarise: We need to know, are you using `biblatex` or not. Also we'd like to see / have mentioned your bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico now that OP has confirmed that they use `natbib`, I've retracted the dupe flag

Comment: @R.Saeiti My solution was for `biblatex`, based on the tag on your question. If you don't actually use the package, you should remove the `biblatex` tag.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker I removed the biblatex tag, sorry

Comment: @OlegLobachev I use natbib and the style is agsm.

Comment: @R.Saeiti - Your question about the lack of truncation of certain citation call-outs to `FirstAuthor et al` [has been asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297271/5001). The `agsm` bibliography style as well as its close relative, the `dcu` bibliography style, have as one of their well-known distinguishing features a non-truncation of citation call-outs if the entries share the same first author but have different other authors. That's why you aren't getting citation call-outs of the form `(Hughes et al., 2018a,b)`. Your best alternative is to find a different bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico Not sure, but I think I show an example of another author (McCulloch and Neuhaus) who published two papers in the same year and appears as McCulloch and Neuhaus, 2011a and McCulloch and Neuhaus, 2011b. The `agsm` style distinguished this but not Hughes's papers.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the link, The second answer works with me. I added letters `a` and `b` in the `year`. I know this is not a good way, but it solves my problem.

Comment: @R.Saeiti - On your first comment: If there are entries with the same two authors and the same publication year, no bibliography style that produces authoryear-style citation call-outs will have any problems producing the expected call-outs. What's "special" [!] about the `agsm` style (and the `dcu` style too, for that matter) is how they treat entries with (a) *three or more* authors with the same first-listed author, (b) the same publication year, and (c) [crucially] a different total number of authors. It's in such cases when `agsm` is set *not* to truncate the respective lists of authors.

Comment: @Mico I see that for this reason `agsm` works good with authors  McCulloch and Neuhaus and not for Hughes. Thanks for this explanation.