# BibTeX same first author, same year but multiple papers: cite as a, b, c etc

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

My issue is exactly the same as in this thread. Except that I am using "bibtex" and not "biblatex."

[biblatex same first author same year: cite as “a”, “b” etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251285/biblatex-same-first-author-same-year-cite-as-a-b-etc)

Does someone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use natbib:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{IngerEtAl2006a,
  title={Using daily ration models and stable isotope analysis to predict biomass depletion by herbivores},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Mackie, Kerry and Robinson, James A and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Applied Ecology},
  volume={43},
  number={5},
  pages={1022--1030},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  tag={}
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006b,
  title={Prey choice affects the trade-off balance between predation and starvation in an avian herbivore},
  author={Inger, Richard and Bearhop, Stuart and Robinson, James A and Ruxton, Graeme},
  journal={Animal Behaviour},
  volume={71},
  number={7},
 pages={1335--1341},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{IngerEtAl2006c,
  title={Temporal and intrapopulation variation in prey choice of wintering geese determined by stable isotope analysis},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Robinson, James A and Jackson, Andrew L and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Animal Ecology},
  volume={75},
  number={5},
  pages={1190--1200},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\citet{IngerEtAl2006a}, \citet{IngerEtAl2006b}, \citet{IngerEtAl2006c}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, thank you! I was using natbib but it was actually my .bst file that was preventing it. It works with plainnat as in your example and also with apalike.

Comment: Fine. Note that the best way to say thanks is to accept the answer.